# Identify an instance of Google Chrome by PID

Tags: google-chrome, memory, virtual-memory, process-explorer

While working I generally need around 40 windows open at a time and run 100-200 processes.  When memory constraints become an issue, I start picking off the processes that are the most resource intensive and disposable.  Often these are chrome.exe.

It would be helpful to be able to match a particularly memory-hungry instance of chrome to it's PID so I can selectively close it.  That is, if I knew what the page title it is currently open to, I could choose whether it lives or dies.

I've tried Process Explorer to no avail.

In Task Manager, you can go from Application to Process.  Any way to go the other way 'round?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could try to use Chrome's task manager directly. Call it by pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Escape</kbd> in Chrome, or in the contextual menu on the title bar, or the task bar button.

[image]

It will show you the memory used for each page (and allow you to choose which ones to keep or close). You can even add the PID column, in this task manager (contextual menu on the column headers).

Comment: That is fantastic.  had no idea that was there.  Thanks a million (bytes).